# How to activate (or equivalent) my newly saved as workbook - Excel VBA marco

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add a new sheet on a newly saved as workbook (successful). Then copy a range of cells from this new workbook to the new sheet (unsuccessful). Currently the script seems to copy the range from the previous workbook but will paste them in the new workbook on the desired worksheet. I'm struggling to have it copy the range from the new workbook.

Here is my current script:

```
Sub SaveAsWorkbookWNewName()

Dim FName           As String
Dim FPath           As String
Dim NewBook         As Workbook

Set DataWSheet = Worksheets("Pub list")
Set BranchField = DataWSheet.Range("C12", DataWSheet.Range("C12").End(xlDown))
Set wsPubBrand = Worksheets("Pub brand schedule one page")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'switching off the alert button

FPath = "C:PATH\Pubs"

For Each BranchName In BranchField

    Workbooks.Open "C:PATH/workbook"

    FName = BranchName & ".xlsm" ' change to .xls for speed
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=FPath & "\" & FName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    
    Set NewWSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)) ' insert a new Worksheet
    NewWSheet.name = BranchName 'named after that branch
    
    wsPubBrand.[C5].Value = ActiveSheet.name
    wsPubBrand.Range("A1:EJ64").Copy Destination:=NewWSheet.Range("A1:EJ64")
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

Next BranchName

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'switching on the alert button

End Sub
```

Some issues obviously come in with the for each loop.
I have tried to;
Activate the new workbook - unsuccessful,
open the new workbook - unsuccessful,
assign new workbook to variable and put in front of 'wsPubBrand' - unsuccessful,
and more...

I really hope this makes sense. If you need any clarification, please ask. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The reason for this method and not just to create a new workbook and copy these values in is because I have a dropdown list I need to remain. This save as method does this.

Comment: What do you mean by "copy a range of cells from this new workbook to the new sheet"? Which "new workbook? Your code tries copying from `wsPubBrand` to the newly added sheet. What does not work, from this point of view?

Comment: Set the rage to copy before the loop then in the loop you can copy and paste.   Before the loop to set the copy range.  `set cRng=wsPubBrand.Range("A1:EJ64")` in the loop to copy paste, just need to paste to A1   `cRng.copy  NewWSheet.Range("A1")`

Comment: There is no *previous* or *new* workbook in your code. You are working in the same workbook all the time. If you open a workbook named A and then with code you save it as B, you are working already in workbook B, but you don't have 2 **opened** workbooks  in Excel. You just went from A to B. **But** you will have 2 files (A and B). Do you mean to open then A and copy data from there?

Comment: The "new wokbook" per say is the newly saved file. So it currently saveas's the open workbook saving it as the "BranchName". Following this I want my commands to opporate in this new file/ BranchName workbook. 
Does this clear things up?

Comment: @FaneDuru by copy range of cells I mean I want to copy a selected range of cells in this newly created file/workbook into the newsheet into this newly created/savedas file/workbook. 
Does this clear that up?

Comment: @Davesexcel Thank you Dave but this doesn't help with my original question. but thanks for the improvement.

Comment: It is not clear at all. At least, for me... When you say "I'm struggling to have it copy the range from the new workbook", what do you mean? Do you want copying from the saved workbook to itself (in the new inserted sheet)? If so, you shouldn't use `wsPubBrand.Range("A1:EJ64").Copy`. You should set the desired sheet of the respective workbook and copy from it. But it looks strange to copy from itself. You maybe try saying something else...